# Does a Pear tree get more fruit on the side facing the sun?

Tags: fruit-trees, pear

We have a large (more than 12 meters high) Pear tree in our garden.

I have the feeling that it gets more fruit on the south facing side (I live in Sweden, so that would be the side facing the sun). I have tried finding litterature to support my feeling, but I have not yet found any.

Is there such an effect on Pear trees in particular or fruit trees in general? Does there exist a good reference in litterature where this is explained?

Thanks!

[image: large pear tree]

Comment: FWIW I have never observed such an effect (here in central Europe).